# Copy specific nodes to the new generated xml

Tags: xml, xslt

i have the following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>

    <students>
        <student rollno="393">
            <firstname>
                <isDisplayInTOC>false</isDisplayInTOC>
                <lastname>Kad</lastname>                    
                <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
                    <marks>85</marks>
            </firstname>
        </student>

        <student rollno="493">
            <firstname>
                <isDisplayInTOC>true</isDisplayInTOC>
                <lastname>Gupta
                    <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
                    <marks>95</marks></lastname>
            </firstname>
        </student>

        <student rollno="593">
            <firstname>
                <isDisplayInTOC>false</isDisplayInTOC>
                <lastname>Singh
                    <nickname>Jazz</nickname></lastname>
                    <marks>90</marks>
            </firstname>
        </student>
    </students>
</class>
```

The xsl i am using is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="firstname">  
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|text|lastname"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text">  
    <isDisplayInTOC>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </isDisplayInTOC>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output i am getting is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class>
    <students>
        <student rollno="393">
            <firstname>
                <lastname>Kad</lastname>
            </firstname>
        </student>
        <student rollno="493">
            <firstname>
                <lastname>
                    Gupta
                    <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
                    <marks>95</marks>
                </lastname>
            </firstname>
        </student>
        <student rollno="593">
            <firstname>
                <lastname>
                    Singh
                    <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
                </lastname>
            </firstname>
        </student>
    </students>
</class>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>
    <students>
    <student rollno="393">
        <firstname>
            <text>true</text>
            <lastname>Kad</lastname>
            <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
            <marks>85</marks>
        </firstname>
    </student>

    <student rollno="493">
        <firstname>
            <text>true</text>
            <lastname>
                Gupta
                <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
                <marks>95</marks>
            </lastname>
        </firstname>
    </student>

    <student rollno="593">
        <firstname>
            <text>true</text>
            <lastname>
                Singh
                <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
            </lastname>
            <marks>90</marks>
        </firstname>
    </student>
</students>
<Employees>
    <student rollno="393">
        <firstname>
            <isDisplayInTOC>false</isDisplayInTOC>
            <lastname>Kad</lastname>
        </firstname>
    </student>

    <student rollno="493">
        <firstname>
            <isDisplayInTOC>true</isDisplayInTOC>
            <lastname>
                Gupta
                <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
                <marks>95</marks>
            </lastname>
        </firstname>
    </student>

    <student rollno="593">
        <firstname>
            <isDisplayInTOC>false</isDisplayInTOC>
            <lastname>
                Singh
                <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
            </lastname>
        </firstname>
    </student>
</Employees>
</class>
```

i want to create an xslt file which copies all the data till the 'lastname' node in a new xml and leaves the nodes below this node as it is.
i am able to traverse till lastname but not able to copy the firstname nodes except the lastname in it.....i am also able to copy the lastname node but not anything above it
Please Help!

Comment: Please include your xsl in the question

Comment: ... and provide a sample output.

Comment: that is the **last updated xsl** i am using.....i am able to reach nearby my desired output but not in proper format and also not the result is desired.....i am not able to find my mistake....please help

Comment: Your question is not clear, esp. the "*copies all the data till the 'lastname' node in a new xml and leaves the nodes below this node as it is*" part. To me, "*copies*" and  "*leaves  as it is*" is the same thing. Please show the exact output you expect to get.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - i have attached the desired output as well...hope it ll help u in understanding the question n u might help me too

Comment: Your added output makes no sense. it contains information that is not in the input - and each student has a different structure. Please show some consideration for the people that are trying to help you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i think you haven't seen the input properly.....the output totally comes out of the input...please give it a look first rather than complaining again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your expected output, I am assuming the following logic

- Copy all `student` nodes as-is with the exception of `firstName`
- For `firstname` add a `text` element, and copy everything else other than `isDiplayInTOC`
- Also create an `Employees` node after the existing `students` node which contains a copy of the `student`
- For the `Student` nodes under `Employees` only include `isDisplayInTOC` and `lastname`

For the first rule, you make use of the [XSLT identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To transform `firstname` have a separate template

```
<xsl:template match="firstname">
  <xsl:copy>
    <text>true</text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::isDisplayInTOC)]" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

For copying the `Student` nodes under `Employees` it may be better to make use of an `xsl:for-each` to avoid clashing templates, with a possible exception of the `firstname`

```
<Employees>
  <xsl:for-each select="student">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="firstname" mode="employee"/>
    </xsl:copy>            
  </xsl:for-each>
</Employees>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="students">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="student"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <Employees>
      <xsl:for-each select="student">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="firstname" mode="employee"/>
        </xsl:copy>            
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Employees>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="firstname">
    <xsl:copy>
      <text>true</text>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::isDisplayInTOC)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="firstname" mode="employee">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="isDisplayInTOC|lastname" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Tim, i need a bit change in my xsl. i want the previous data as well as the new extracted data(which i referred as desired output above) in the same xml but the new extracted data should be in a different node, say 'Employee' and one more thing....it is actually displaying the unecessary "isDisplayInTOC>true</isDisplayInTOC>"  which should be copied automatically and not manually....i hope i am not asking for much....thanks.....be looking up for your positive revert....thanks again

Comment: I've made a change to my answer, but your desired output does not contain any reference to `Employee` so I don't know how that fits in.

Comment: still not working.....it is not taking out the '<isDisplayInTOC>true</isDisplayInTOC>' node in the xml so generated by xsl. in all the firstname nodes.....it is escaping all the nodes that is below the firstname node and directly going to the lastname node and printing it

Comment: i have updated my xsl , the output i am getting and the desired output by me in my question.....please help....thnx

Comment: I can updatw my answer, but can you confirm you input XML and desired output are exactly what you want? Previously you had a `text` node in your input XML and a `isDisplayInTOC` in your output. Now I see that has been reversed and `isDisplayInTOC` in your input. Thank you!

Comment: that is the last update.....the above provided is my input xml and desired xml.....extremely sorry.....n thnx too

Comment: I've amended my answer to give some new XSLT which produces the desired output you have shown, based on your input.

Comment: no its still not working....same issue as above....thanks for your support anyways

Comment: Can you explain why you mean by "not working" as when I tested my XSLT at http://xslttest.appspot.com/ using your input XML, the output XML produced does match your desired output. Thank you

Comment: it is only displaying the data for <lastname> in <employees> rest all that should match the desired output is not giving out as output......that-is-why....thanks

Comment: In your desired output, you only have `<isDisplayInTOC>` and `<lastname>` showing for the data in `<employees>` and the XSLT in my answer does produce that.

Comment: but you are producing that manually....i want it to be done automatically....something i need to tell you is that its not my original xml....its just a sample....i am applying your xslt with changes on my original xml but its not working as we are transforming that part manually......sorry if i am troubling you

Comment: I am afraid I don't think I have any more time to spare to look at this. If the XML you are showing in your question does not represent your actual XML, and if you are making changes to the XSLT I have given, then there is very little more I can do to help you. Sorry. I would suggest you delete this question, and add a new question, but showing XML that truly reflects what you require. Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which contains good advice on how to ask a well structured question. Thank you.

Comment: its totally okay....thanx anywayz......yeah i ll take a look at it and inform you that too

Comment: i have uploaded a new question with my actual xml.....thanks for the link.....i actually learnt for uploading a proper question...thanks again